# Should impact on schedule because of scope change be reported as delay?

Tags: scope

In my company, if there is any delay in the schedule I need to report the delay-reason and countermeasure. Sometimes this delay happens because of scope change.

My question is: Should I report it as "delay" in that case what would be the countermeasure? or I should just report updating the schedule without reporting delay?

Comment: Do you maybe mean *consequence*, if not, what do you mean by _countermeasure_?

Comment: Can you give an example for a *countermeasure*? For example for a delay caused by a supplier not delivering on time (or reporting a delay on heir end).

Comment: Doesn't countermeasure mean mitigation / remediation?  I think he's talking about schedule recovery.

Comment: the delay in schedule could happen due to different reasons, for example : in-accurate estimation, due to communication  issue, not enough buffer time, external  dependency or blocker not resolved in due time etc. so in counter measure we normally report what action we have taken so that we can avoid the situations next time .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you had a scope change, a legitimate one that was approved via your change process, then you should also have a corresponding and proportional schedule and cost change.  This means that the delay is not a delay but rather a new schedule target. Your first schedule baseline goes away as if it never existed.  Same as your scope baseline and cost baseline.

If you didn't change your schedule or cost with this scope change, then your change process is broken.